# Multiple try and except in one block of for loops

Tags: python, selenium

I'm writing a code which has multiple for loops (web-scraping). The problem is that I keep getting an error of StaleElement because of which I need to include try and except in every line of code but this is creating a problem of nested for loops in my code.

This is the homepage: https://www.ine.es/censo/es/seleccion_inframunicipal.jsp

Also, my for loops run to two pages, as I'm selecting through multiple lists. 
For example, I'm probably getting the indentation wrong because the for loops are not being nested correctly.

My code looks like this:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cabe"]/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[5]/a/b').click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cabe"]/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[17]/a/b').click()

first_op = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/form[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/select/option')
second_op = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/form[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/select/option')
third_op = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/form[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/select/option')
fourth_op =  browser.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/form[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/select/option')

for elem in first_op:
    elem.click()
    for ele in second_op:
        ele.click()
        browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/a')
        for el in third_op:
            el.click()
            browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/a[1]/img')
            browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/input')
```

Comment: Please read [mcve] and edit your question accordingly. we don't know How the website or html structure looks like and what other trials and errors you got. By following above said post it will make your question more understandable and more likely attract more answers.Do not add images of code its bad practice

Comment: @dev corrected! sorry. please check my question again